# Fetch single line of text from a row in a table using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table in which a row contains few lines of text. I want to fetch only one line at a time and then insert it into a separate new row in a new table.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: can you include in your post your input and your expected output

Comment: you need to explain this part : `want to fetch only one line at a time`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to explode these string? Then loop.

```
$list = explode("\n", $row['Comment']);

foreach($list as $line){
 echo $line;
}
```